# PERL extract the substring using REGEX

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a substring from the below formatted string.

STRING = ABC123.Txt
GOAL: ABC.Txt

The pearl statement i wrote is giving me a syntax error on the regular expression line at ")("

```
$S= "ABC123.Txt";
$S=~/([A-Z])([0-9])(\.[A-Za-z])/;
print "$1$3";
```

I am new to regular expressions so any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It isn't giving you a "syntax error" at all -- that's syntactically valid Perl code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
/([A-Z])/
```

will only match a *single* capital letter.  If you want one or more capital letters to match, you need to follow the pattern with a `+`:

```
$S=~/([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)(\.[A-Za-z]+)/;
```